# Expected function is a called but none of the functions inside of it are never called

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I currently doing some unit test for an Angular application using Jasmine and Karma. I'm having a problem with a unit test that must open a modal, change some value of the form and save it. Everthing is doing well until it reaches inside the promise for the `open()`of my modal service and call `saveAttribute()` function.

The expects seems to have been called `saveAttribute()` successfully, but none of the functions inside of it are never called, even the `hasValidRegex()` function, despite being the first thing called in the `saveAttribute()` function. I also tried using a console log at the beginning of the `saveAttribute()` function but it never reaches it and print nothing apart of the function begin successfully called. Am I missing something?

**.spec file**

```
it('should save edited values in an selected attribute', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockOpenModalResult = {
      result: new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('Save'))
    };
    spyOn(ngbModal, 'open').and.returnValue(mockOpenModalResult);
    spyOn(component, 'saveAttribute');
    spyOn(component, 'hasValidRegex').and.returnValue(true);
    spyOn(siteService, 'saveRequestTypeAttribute').and.returnValue(1155);
    spyOn(component, 'updateSiteTreeView');
    spyOn(component, 'clearFields');
    
    component.openModalInternal(mockAttributeRootNode, mockDetectChanges);
    flush();
    
    expect(component.saveAttribute).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockAttributeRootNode, mockDetectChanges);
    expect(component.hasValidRegex).toHaveBeenCalled();


    expect(siteService.saveRequestTypeAttribute).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockRequestTypeAttribute);
expect(component.updateSiteTreeView).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockRequestTypeAttribute);
    expect(component.clearFields).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));
```

**Component.ts**

```
openModalInternal(attributeRootNode: SiteTreeNode, detectChanges: Function) {
    this.title = this.editMode ? 'Edit' : 'Add';
    const ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
      ariaLabelledBy: this.title,
      backdrop: 'static',
      scrollable: true,
      size: 'xl',
      centered: true,
      keyboard: false
    };
    this.modalService.open(this.requestTypeAttributeTypeModal, ngbModalOptions).result.then(result => {
      if (result === 'Save') {
        console.log('test reaches this part of the code and calls saveAttributes successfully')
        this.saveAttribute(attributeRootNode, detectChanges);
      } else if (result === 'Remove') {
        this.removeAttribute(attributeRootNode, detectChanges);
      } else {
        this.clearFields();
      }
    });
  }
  
  
  saveAttribute(attributeRootNode: SiteTreeNode, detectChanges: Function) {
    if (!this.hasValidRegex()) {
      return;
    }
    const locationId: number = this.storageService.getLocationId();
    const myObjType: item = {
      // ...
    };
    this.siteService.saveRequestTypeAttribute(item).subscribe(id => {
      item.AttributeId = id;
      this.alertMessageService.setSuccessMessage([SuccessMessage.SuccessMessage]);
      this.updateSiteTreeView(attributeRootNode, detectChanges);
    });
    this.clearFields();
  }
```

**Errors:**
[image: Karma erros]

**Note:** Can't show you mocked data because of a disclosure matter. But I don't think that the mocked data is causing this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know the issue. The issue is this:

```
spyOn(component, 'saveAttribute');
```

When you `spyOn` a method, you are losing its implementation details and you can just see whether if it was called or not or how many times it was called. To still have the implementation details, you have to use `.and.callThrough()` to actually call the function every time it is called.

Change the line to:

```
spyOn(component, 'saveAttribute').and.callThrough();
```

and the test should hopefully pass.

Comment: Thanks lot! It worked for me. I was confused about the actual meaning of `spyOn`.